# Discord.js Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

token collect all but can't run bot

Discord.js Version 12

I can't type my real token

```
client.login('')
```

[ERROR] - Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.

Comment: Are you sure you are using bot token not the client one ?

Answer (score 1):

Try generating new token on Discord developer portal and use it instead

Comment: can't bro it say token_invaild I'm sure for that token are true i'm copy it but it say invaild token